# Why changing signals causes NameErrors in a sane code? - PyGtk issue

Tags: python, application-development, pygtk, glade

I'm working on a very simple app for Ubuntu. I've asked a question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173718/global-variable-error-despite-declaring-variable-as-global-in-each-function), and it seems that the issue I am having is caused by signals, not by the scope of variables, as I originally thought. The problem I am having is that when `TextBox` emits a signal through `activate` the whole code works without a glitch. But when I change the signal to `insert-at-click` it returns NameErrors in every non-`TextBox`-linked function. Now, It is highly possible I am doing something completely wrong here, but is it at least probable that signals could affect global variable assignments?

The code in its current form giving me NameErrors:

```
def on_servername_insertatcursor(self, widget):
global output  
output = StringIO.StringIO()         
servername = widget.get_text()
output.write("USHARE_NAME="+servername+'\n')

def on_netif_changed(self, widget):
netif = widget.get_active_text()
global output
output.write("USHARE_IFACE="+netif+'\n')

def on_port_insertatcursor(self, widget):
global output
port = widget.get_text()
output.write("USHARE_PORT="+port+'\n')

def on_telprt_insertatcursor(self, widget):
global output
telprt = widget.get_text()
output.write("USHARE_TELNET_PORT="+telprt+'\n')

def on_dirs_insertatcursor(self, widget):
global output
dirs = widget.get_text()
output.write("USHARE_DIR="+dirs+'\n')

def on_iconv_toggled(self, widget):
global output
iconv = widget.get_active()
if iconv == True:
    output.write("USHARE_OVERRIDE_ICONV_ERR="+"True"+'\n')
else:
    output.write("USHARE_OVERRIDE_ICONV_ERR="+"False"+'\n')

def on_webif_toggled(self, widget):
global output
webif = widget.get_active()
if webif == True:
    output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_WEB="+"yes"+'\n')
else:
    output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_WEB="+"no"+'\n')

def on_telif_toggled(self, widget):
global output
telif = widget.get_active()
if telif == True:
    output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_TELNET="+"yes"+'\n')
else:
    output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_TELNET="+"no"+'\n')

def on_xbox_toggled(self, widget):
global output
xbox = widget.get_active()
if xbox == True:
    output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_XBOX="+"yes"+'\n')
else:
    output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_XBOX="+"no"+'\n')

def on_dlna_toggled(self, widget):
global output
dlna = widget.get_active()
if dlna == True:
    output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_DLNA="+"yes"+'\n')
else:
    output.write("USHARE_ENABLE_DLNA="+"no"+'\n')

def on_commit_clicked(self, widget):
commit = output.getvalue()
logfile = open('/home/boywithaxe/Desktop/ushare.conf','w')
logfile.write(commit)

def on_endprogram_clicked(self, widget):
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: @izx: no need to thank me, I need to start being more clear. :)

Comment: Is the current code in the stack exchange what you are currently using and having an issue with?

Comment: @mhall119: yes, that's the most up to date version of the code. I've also added it here for convenience.

Comment: @mhall119: but replacing `insertatcursor` with `activate` runs the code smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the meaning of the `global` statement in Python. Here's what the Python documentation says:

> The global statement ... means that the listed identifiers are to be
>   interpreted as globals. It would be impossible to assign to a global
>   variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals
>   without being declared global.

So, basically, you only need to use `global blah` when you need to assign to a global variable called `blah`. The variable, however, should already exist in the global scope. If you're just accessing a global variable or its methods (as apposied to assigning to it), you don't need to declare it as `global`.

So what you need is something like

```
output = None

def on_servername_insertatcursor(self, widget):
    global output  
    output = StringIO.StringIO()         
    servername = widget.get_text()
    output.write("USHARE_NAME="+servername+'\n')

def on_netif_changed(self, widget):
    netif = widget.get_active_text()
    output.write("USHARE_IFACE="+netif+'\n')

...
```

However, the whole approach with using a global variable and making the whole thing dependent on the order of function calls (on_servername_insertatcursor MUST be called first, otherwise the other functions will fail) is not a good coding practice.

**UPDATE:** Also, it occurred to me that the functions you're showing are in fact methods of a class, is that right? In this case, you can make `output` a member of the class and access it as `self.output`:

```
class MyApp(gtk.Window):

    output = None

    def __init__(...):
        ...
        self.output = StringIO.StringIO()

    def on_servername_insertatcursor(self, widget):    
        servername = widget.get_text()
        self.output.write("USHARE_NAME="+servername+'\n')

    def on_netif_changed(self, widget):
        netif = widget.get_active_text()
        self.output.write("USHARE_IFACE="+netif+'\n')
```

Still, the output of your app is dependent on the order user clicks the buttons, which is not cool. For example if user clicks the "dlna" checkbox twice, there will be 2 lines in the config, which I presume is not what you want.

Comment: Fair point. And I think I just realised what the issue is. Having set a `global` at `def on_servername_activate` (I'm using `activate` right now, as `insertatcursor` doesn't work. I might be using a wrong signal) it **must** be assigned there and then, so that when it goes to `def on_netif_changed` it exists already. I think that's what's causing the problem. Thank you for pointing that out. But now, is there a way of not making the code dependent on the order in which data is input?

Comment: Can you confirm you've seen and tried the code from the UPDATE section? There's no need to use `global` at all.

Regarding the "way of not making the code dependent on the order in which data is input" - can you ask a new question on SO, I'll be happy to answer. It

Comment: ... may be difficult to do that here in the comments

Comment: Yes I have seen the code and reflected it in mine, that is actually the most graceful way out of this ness I couls have hoped for, Thank you! I will post another question on SO regarding the order of data input

Comment: [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181818/how-to-make-the-order-in-which-data-is-input-into-stringio-irrelevant-python) the question on SO